# react pong game state add up wierdly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a pong game I made a player to move by pressing w/s toward top and bottom
but when I change the direction of it it bounces which I don't expect it bounce exponentially
if you change the direction

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(100);

  document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => handleclick(e));

  const handleclick = (e) => {
    const key = e.key;
    console.log(key);
    if (key == "w") {
      setLocation((prevLocation) => prevLocation - 10);
    }
    if (key == "s") {
      setLocation((prevLocation) => prevLocation + 10);
    }
  };

  //! problem is when you change the direction player bounce 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="player1"
        style={{
          top: location + "px",
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is nothing problematic in CSS so I don't consider it here.

//edit i removed setLocation((prevLocation) => prevLocation + 10); and add setLocation(location + 10); but still there is problem state whole app crashes like there is infinite loop and and state changes properly but function inside eventListener execute infinitely and i cahnged keypress to keydown next tried to set another event listner for keyup to removeEventListner of keydown in case maybe it dont go in a infinite loop but still didnt help

now code is like this but still problematic

```
function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(100);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => handleMove(e));

  document.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", (e) => handleMove(e));
  });
  console.log(location);

  const handleMove = (e) => {
    const key = e.key;

    if (key == "w") {
      setLocation(location - 10);
    }
    if (key == "s") {
      setLocation(location + 10);
    }
  };

  //! problem is when you change the direction player bounce

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="player1"
        style={{
          top: location + "px",
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: General programming question: why is your _key_ handler called "handle _click_"? With that covered: look at your variable names. You did not call your state variable `prevLocation`,, you called it `location`, and you're passing a function to `setLocation` instead of just passing it the new value to use.

Comment: handleclick was previous name i didnt change its just a name , and about using a callback now i now there was no need for that i just use setLocation(location -+ 10) and now i change it but a new problem rises after some move whole page freezes like there is infinite loop any idea about that

Comment: Add a second code block that shows what things look like after you changed it. Without code, there's no telling what you may have done wrong. And done say "edit", just extend your post with the new information with a leadin that explains what the next part of the post is about.

Comment: new code added and handleMove still call itself infinite time does adding eventListner inside useEffect can help  and give removeEventListner to return function of useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to cross the React/rest-of-the-page boundary, where you want to listen to document level events, even though React is designed around listening for App-level events.

So you can either solve this by creating run-once event listeners, so that you can "safely" use your useEffect:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(100);

  const handleMove = (e) => {
    const key = e.key;
    if (key === "w") {
      setLocation(location - 10);
    }
    if (key === "s") {
      setLocation(location + 10);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   // register a new event handler every time:
   document.addEventListener("keypress", handleMove, { once: true });
   // making sure to rebind the event every time the location changes:
  }, [location]);

  const locationStyle = {
    position: `fixed`,
    top: `${location}px`,
  };

  return (
    <div style={locationStyle}>{ location }</div>
  );
}
```

But this is super wasteful in the sense that we're constantly creating and destroying event listeners.

Instead, we can do things more "Reactish" by putting the key listening on the App itself, not the document. The upside with this solution is that we've now put the event listening "where it needs to be", with a React-managed persistent event handler, but the downside is that need to focus on the app before it'll receive key events. Thankfully, that's pretty easy by using a "real" side effect this time: after the first render, we just set focus on our app's DOM node:

```
import {  createRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const keyMap = { "w": -10, "s": 10 };

export default function App() {
  // focus on our app, on first load
  const ourApp = createRef(null);
  useEffect(() => ourApp.current.focus(), []);

  // actual app behaviour: update our "location" on key presses
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(100);
  const handleMove = ({key}) => setLocation(location + keyMap[key]);

  const locationStyle = {
    position: `fixed`,
    top: `${location}px`,
  };

  const props = {
    ref: ourApp,
    onKeyDown: handleMove,
    tabIndex: 0,
    style: locationStyle,
  };

  return (
    <div {...props}>{ location }</div>
  );
}
```

Remembering that if we want to be able to focus on things, those things need to have a `tab-index` property, which on the React side means setting a `tabIndex` attribute. We can, of course, now lose focus if someone clicks outside the app, but again the solution there is simple: make the app full width, and full height.

Comment: ty sir for Detailed explanation i got my answer infact becuase i am new i didnt know how to access nodes with ref in react and set onload focus much appreciated. another question is it wrong to get access to a node like coding plain js ? what will happen wrong in react in this case?

Comment: When you use React, React "owns" those nodes. The rest of the page and plain JS can access them just fine, but the way React rendering works, that node may get deleted and completely rebuilt whenever React feels it necessary to do so, and any other JS that has references to the original now points to a dead node that isn't in the DOM anymore. React and plain JS can be made to work together just fine, but how you (need to) do that depends entirely on what functionality you're trying to implement.